# How I can use json object from file (e.g text.json) for my email template to read from in Django

Tags: python, json, django, django-templates

I am using Django to send email templates to users. I want to store all the text show in the HTMl template in json object and reference the text as variable(double {{}}) in the html email template

```
-------> util.py

def send_reset_password_email(user: User):
    reset_token = create_user_reset_password_token(user)
    reset_password_url = '{}/account/password/reset/{}'.format(settings.CLIENT_URL, reset_token)
    params = {
        'reset_password_url': reset_password_url,
        'textdata':   ### how I can reference my json file here
    }
    send_template_email(user.email, 'Reset Password','reset_password.html', params)

------->text.json file
{
  "forget_password_email_template": {
    "title": "This is title",
    "sub_title": "This is Sub title",
    "support": "This is title",
    "help_message": "This is help message"
  },
  "confirmation_email_template": {
    "title": "This is title",
    "sub_title": "This is Sub title",
    "support": "This is title",
    "help_message": "This is help message"
  }
}
-------> reset_password.html
<html>
.......
 <p style="margin: 0;" class="forget-password-text">
Forgot your password? Let’s get you a new one! {{params.textdata}}</p><br>
.....
<<html/>
```

I have tried `import json` but it didn't work.
Thanks, and if there is other any better way to achieve this??

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this by locating `file.json` at the same level of `manage.py`.
see screenshot below!.
and then

```
import json
 
with open('emails_text.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

    params = {
        'reset_password_url': reset_password_url,
        'textdata': data,
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Seems like you are on the right path. This should do the trick:

```py
import json
 
with open('text.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

    params = {
        'reset_password_url': reset_password_url,
        'textdata': data,
    }
```

Comment: I tried the above and I am getting an error saying `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'text.json'` though the above worked for python(I did testing on a seperate files) but not for django @Sorin Burghiu

Comment: `text.json` is all you give in the answer. Please rephrase your question if this is not what you are looking for.